# Can I ask "Will it be soon?"

Tags: questions

The expression

> It will be soon ...

is used widely but

> Will it be soon (because I am in urgent need of ...)?

seems strange.

Can I ask like that? How to express if I couldn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with many languages, there are various ways to ask this question based on how polite you want to be?  For example, these are about as polite as English gets without seeming obsequious or servile:

> Do you think it may be possible to get a response soon?
>
> Would it be possible for you to respond soon?

Meanwhile, it's entirely possible to be rude:

> I want a response ASAP!  (as soon as possible)

Or somewhere in-between:

> How soon will you get back to me?
>
> Could you get back to me soon?

Of course there are many other ways to ask this question, especially in a business context.  My personal favorite:

> This is fairly urgent, so a prompt response is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> Will it be soon (because I am in urgent need of ...)?

There is a lot of difference in meaning between *soon* and *urgent*, so I would not join them this way. Better would be something like:

> Will it be **really** soon (because I am in urgent need of ...)?

which better matches the urgency. Or if less urgent, perhaps:

> Will it be **soon**, because I can't finish my project without your information?

which explains the necessity without a specific time frame. *soon* has a much broader implication time-wise.